# various onclick events fired depending on pressed time but with a same clicked_id?

Tags: javascript

**What I want to achieve:** every button will fire various events depending on the time how long a button was pressed. I know how to make it for a specific button but what if I have a few of them and I don't know yet which one will be clicked and for how long? With one button it will be easy with `id="button1"onclick="alert1(this.id);" but what in a such case?

Is it even possible to do it with a vanilla javascript?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Timeout</title>
<style>                                                         
</style>    
</head>
<body>


<div id="test">
    <button id="button1">   Sentence where 2 functions are directly onclick. </button>
    <button id="button2" >Sentence where either 2 functions or 1 function will be activated, depending on time used </button>
  </div>

<script>
function alert1 (clicked_id){
var onID = (clicked_id);
alert1(onID);
}
</script>

<script>
function alert2 (clicked_id){
var onID = (clicked_id);
alert2(onID);
}
</script>
<script>
    function alert3 (clicked_id){
    var onID = (clicked_id);
    alert3(onID);
    }
</script>

<script>
    function alert1 (clicked_id){
    var onID = (clicked_id);
    alert1(onID);
    }
    </script>


<script>
function newaler (clicked_id){
var onID = (clicked_id);
alert1(onID);alert2(onID);
}
</script>

<script>
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      e.target.starttime = Date.now();
    }
  });
  
  document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      let endtime = Date.now();
      let delta = endtime - parseInt(e.target.starttime);
      console.log(delta);
      if (delta > 0 && delta < 700) {
      alert3(onID);
      }
      if (delta > 700) {
      alert1(onID);alert2(onID);
      }
    }
  });
  </Script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
let lastClickedBtn = null
let clickTimes = {}

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      clickTimes[e.target.id] = Date.now();
      lastClickedBtn = e.target
    }
});

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      let endtime = Date.now();
      let delta = endtime - clickTimes[lastClickedBtn.id];
      ...
    }
});
```

Comment: AhmadKZX, thank you very much for your reply. I really appreciate. I just logged to my account. I can't make it work what you send me but maybe I am doing it all wrong. I will try a bit more.

Comment: In console I have an information "NaN" not a number when these alert1, alert2, alert3 should return an id in a form of alert as a popup windows such as "alert1"

Comment: log endTime and clickTimes[lastClickedBtn.id] and make sure they are have correct value. if they are correct try parseInt when calculating their difference in delta val

Comment: Thanks Ahmad I appreciate your help. I will try like you recommended.

Comment: I think it is not a problem with exact numbers but here `<button id="button1">` . Here in my code is missing now `onclick="newaler(this.id);"` which I want to make global and pass a `var onID = (clicked_id)` on demand to various events, depending on time for how long the button was pressed. I will try a bit more and write here if I find out anything.

Comment: If I do this then I have `Untitled-12.html:39 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` and `onID` is still undefined. ` var onID = target.id;` also would give a feedback target is not defined.

Comment: `let onID=(e.target.id);` solved it. No more needed was `this.id` inside each span, so I marked your answer as correct even if I won't use your code. Without you I wouldn't realize this small thing which I just wrote, thanks.